# Wildfly Database Authentication : Adding date calculations into the principals query

Tags: mysql, wildfly

I am trying to implement a login expiry feature in an application running with the Wildfly Database Authentication Module.

Since there seems to be no way to trigger custom code on successful authentication , or any sort of HttpSessionListener type of approach to get this information I thought I could add a WHERE clause onto the principal query in standalone.xml to satisfy my goals:

```
  <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
        ...
         <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from parent where email=? and CURDATE() <= login_expiry_date "/>
        ...
   </login-module>
```

But Wildfly outputs a stacktrace saying

```
 com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected '<'  in attribute value
```

The business requirement I am trying to meet dictates that a user's login must expires 2 weeks after being initiated, and can be manually re-initiated by administrator.

Should I continue attempting to hack this business logic into the principals query in standalone.xml or would I be better off using something like a batch process to expire the users?

Comment: You say "Since there seems to be no way to trigger custom code on successful authentication...". Actually there is, please take a look at HttpServletRequest.login method - if it executes without exception, it means you're authenticated and still in the realm of your own code.

Comment: I was under the impression that the HttpServletRequest.login() method is a programmatic approach to authentication...I didn't realise I could use it together with a container-based mechanism.  But it's not a problem, I managed to meet the business requirement by using the query shown in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

< is not valid for an xml property string. You have to escape it to &lt;

```
<module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from parent where email=? and CURDATE() &lt;= login_expiry_date "/>
```

Comment: Oh.So simple! Thanks very much